# Get XML field value javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following XML, it's coming as string from a request. How can I get the capital value (Washington, DC Paris)?

```
<Country>
    <USA>
    <Capital>"Washington, D.C"</Capital>
    </USA>
    <France>
    <Capital>"Paris"</Capital>
    </France>
</Country>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) :

```js
var xml = `<Country>
    <USA>
    <Capital>"Washington, D.C"</Capital>
    </USA>
    <France>
    <Capital>"Paris"</Capital>
    </France>
</Country>`

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "application/xml");
doc.querySelectorAll('Capital').forEach(
  (cap) => console.log(cap.textContent));
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the answer with jquery. With jquery it can be easily done as,

```js
var text = `<Country>
    <USA>
    <Capital>"Washington, D.C"</Capital>
    </USA>
    <France>
    <Capital>"Paris"</Capital>
    </France>
</Country>`;
$(text).find("Capital").each(function(){
console.log($(this).text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```